# How to get a term custom field value in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, taxonomy-terms

I've created a 'color' custom field for `pa_color` taxonomy terms, by native ways as follows:

This is my code:

```
add_action( 'pa_color_add_form_fields', 'themename_pa_color_add_term_fields' );
 
function themename_pa_color_add_term_fields( $taxonomy ) {
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
    <label for="themename_pa_color">PA Color</label>
    <input type="color" name="themename_pa_color" id="themename_pa_color" class="wpColorChoose" />
    <p>Field description may go here.</p>
    </div>
    <?php 
}

add_action( 'pa_color_edit_form_fields', 'themename_pa_color_edit_term_fields', 10, 2 );
 
function themename_pa_color_edit_term_fields( $term, $taxonomy ) {
 
    $value = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'themename_pa_color', true );
 
    echo '<tr class="form-field">
    <th>
        <label for="themename_pa_color">PA Color</label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <input name="themename_pa_color" id="themename_pa_color" type="color" class="wpColorChoose" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) .'" />
        <p class="description">Field description may go here.</p>
    </td>
    </tr>';
}

add_action( 'created_pa_color', 'themename_pa_color_save_term_fields' );
add_action( 'edited_pa_color', 'themename_pa_color_save_term_fields' );
 
function themename_pa_color_save_term_fields( $term_id ) {
 
    update_term_meta(
        $term_id,
        'themename_pa_color',
        sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'themename_pa_color' ] )
    );
 
}
```

How can I get their values to the place I need?

When trying to use `$term->themename_pa_color`, it doesn't work.

It works with name and description default fields, like `$term->name` or `$term->description`, but not with my field.

That's how I created it, it correctly saves values.

Comment: Maybe something else is wrong. It saves values in the admin bar, but  that's I see after ` $terms = get_terms( 'pa_color' );

echo "<pre>";

print_r($terms);

echo "</pre>";`

Comment: `<pre>Array
(
    [0] =&gt; WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] =&gt; 130
            [name] =&gt; Beige
            [slug] =&gt; beige
            [term_group] =&gt; 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] =&gt; 130
            [taxonomy] =&gt; pa_color
            [description] =&gt; 375sdkfjsdgtjdsop
            [parent] =&gt; 0
            [count] =&gt; 1
            [filter] =&gt; raw
        )
    
)</pre>`

Comment: thank you for your help! the result is `<div class="d-flex"><?php 
$terms = get_terms( 'pa_color' );
 if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){?><ul><?php  
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {?>
     <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term )?>"><div class="pa_color-bg" style=" border: 1px solid; background: <?php echo get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'themename_pa_color', true ); ?> ">&#9679;</div> <span><?php echo $term->name ?></span></a></li><?php  } } ?></ul></div>`, finally I see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is adding a custom field to the terms from "pa_color" taxonomy… So this is about **term meta data** which is never included in the `WP_Term` Object, and so not accessible as a property from that `WP_Term` Object.

So the answer is in your code. You need to use the WordPress function `get_term_meta()` like in your own code *(in your 2nd function)*:

```
$value = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'themename_pa_color', true );

echo $value; // Display value
```

*(where `$term->term_id` is the term Id and `themename_pa_color` the meta key)*…